# Sorted insert on a python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

Good morning everybody, 
Here is my function that is supposed to make a recursive sorted insertion of a couple of data:

```
def sorted_insert(w_i,sim,neighbors):
    if neighbors==[]:
        neighbors.append((w_i,sim))
    elif neighbors[0][1]<sim:
        neighbors.insert(0,(w_i,sim))
    else:
        sorted_insert(w_i,sim,neighbors[1:])
    return neighbors
```

The problem is, this function doesn't insert values in the middle, here is a series of insertions :

```
>>> n=[]
>>> n=sorted_insert("w1",0.6,n)
>>> n=sorted_insert("w1",0.3,n)
>>> n=sorted_insert("w1",0.5,n)
>>> n=sorted_insert("w1",0.8,n)
>>> n=sorted_insert("w1",0.7,n)
>>> n
[('w1', 0.8), ('w1', 0.6)]
```

Is there someone that can correct my function ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are inserting into a *copy* of the list, as you pass in a copy on recursive calls: `neighbors[1:]`.

Comment: Not speaking of the lack of proper indentation

Comment: Also, instead of reinventing the wheel, use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module and its `insort*` methods

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the indentation is destroyed while pasting the code (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def sorted_insert(w_i,sim,neighbors, i=0):
    if len(neighbors) == i or sim > neighbors[i][1]:
        neighbors.insert(i, (w_i,sim))
    else:
        sorted_insert(w_i,sim,neighbors, i+1)
n=[]
sorted_insert("w1",0.6,n)
sorted_insert("w1",0.3,n)
sorted_insert("w1",0.5,n)
sorted_insert("w1",0.8,n)
sorted_insert("w1",0.7,n)
print n
# [('w1', 0.8), ('w1', 0.7), ('w1', 0.6), ('w1', 0.5), ('w1', 0.3)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! that's what I was looking for !